# Get AuthenticationInfo in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How do I get the `AuthenticationInfo` property from the HttpContext in ASP.NET Core 2.0. I understand that with the redesign of Security in ASP.NET Core 2.0 the `AuthenticationManager` is now obsolete and that I should remove `.Authentication`.

I used to do something like this in 1.1.2

```
var info = await httpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync("Automatic");
info.Properties.StoreTokens(new List<AuthenticationToken>
{
    new AuthenticationToken
    {
        Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken,
        Value = accessToken
    },
    new AuthenticationToken
    {
        Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken,
        Value = refreshToken
    }
});

await httpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Automatic", info.Principal, info.Properties);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`AuthenticationManager.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync(string)` was replaced by `IAuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(string)` in 2.0: it now returns an `AuthenticateResult` but it works exactly the same way.

Your snippet can be updated to:

```
var result = await httpContext.AuthenticateAsync();
result.Properties.StoreTokens(new List<AuthenticationToken>
{
    new AuthenticationToken
    {
        Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken,
        Value = accessToken
    },
    new AuthenticationToken
    {
        Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken,
        Value = refreshToken
    }
});

await httpContext.SignInAsync(result.Principal, result.Properties);
```

Comment: Note "Automatic" is no longer a key word. Just call `.AuthenticateAsync();`

Comment: @Tratcher nice catch, thanks. I was sure I had edited my answer to replace Automatic by [scheme] but looks like I forgot to save my edit. That said, you're right it's probably easier to use the default scheme for both authentication and sign-in, so I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Pinpoint I make use of IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator class and validate the user and now I have the token, expiration date and refresh_token. How should I pass refresh_token to renew the token. Is this the approach that needs to be followed for custom token refresh or any  other. Plz suggest.

Comment: @User I have no idea what `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` is. It's not part of ASP.NET Core, at least.

Comment: @Pinpoint Yes, its part of IdentityServer4. Can you plz gave a sample or  any link that could help me in renewing the token in Asp.Net core.

Comment: @User you should open a separate question. It's not really related to this one.